# Create new column based on whether date is between other dates, over multiple time periods

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a table with multiple rows person, and the date that each tax year ends:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~ID,       ~TAX_YEAR_END_DATE,
                       "01",      "2009-04-06",
                       "01",      "2010-04-06",
                       "01",      "2011-04-06",
                       "02",      "2010-04-06",
                       "02",      "2011-04-06",
                       "02",      "2012-04-06")
```

And another table, with multiple rows per person, giving the start date and end date for periods of work:

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(~ID,     ~START_DATE,   ~END_DATE,
                       "01",    "2007-09-11",  "2010-04-06",
                       "02",    "2008-06-06",  "2010-04-06",
                       "02",    "2011-09-09",  "2014-04-06")
```

The `END_DATE` is always on 6th April, and everybody always has a `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` - there are no `NULL`s.

I want to add a new `STATUS` column to the first table, saying whether or not each person was EMPLOYED or NOT for each year. This is what it would look like for the above example:

```
ID      TAX_YEAR_END_DATE   STATUS
01      2009-04-06          EMPLOYED
01      2010-04-06          EMPLOYED
01      2011-04-06          NOT
02      2010-04-06          EMPLOYED
02      2011-04-06          NOT
02      2012-04-06          EMPLOYED
```

I've figured out that I can join the tables by `ID`, then apply some rules while using `mutate()` to create a new column - if the `TY_END_DATE` is between the `START_DATE` and `END_DATE` then the `STATUS` is EMPLOYED, and if it isn't then the `STATUS` is NOT.

Where I get stuck is with borrowers who have more than one period of employment in the second table. In these cases the rows in the first table get duplicated (or more) when I carry out the join, and I've not been able to figure out an alternative way of doing this.

I'm using R, would prefer data.table as it's normally quicker, but dplyr might be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using non equi join in data.table:

```
DT1[, status := c("NOT","EMP")[
    DT2[.SD, on=.(ID, START_DATE<=TAX_YEAR_END_DATE, END_DATE>=TAX_YEAR_END_DATE),
        by=.EACHI, .N>0L]$V1 + 1L
]]
```

output:

```
   ID TAX_YEAR_END_DATE status
1:  1        2009-04-06    EMP
2:  1        2010-04-06    EMP
3:  1        2011-04-06    NOT
4:  2        2010-04-06    EMP
5:  2        2011-04-06    NOT
6:  2        2012-04-06    EMP
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- fread("ID      TAX_YEAR_END_DATE
01      2009-04-06
01      2010-04-06
01      2011-04-06
02      2010-04-06
02      2011-04-06
02      2012-04-06")[, 
    TAX_YEAR_END_DATE := as.IDate(TAX_YEAR_END_DATE)]

cols <- c("START_DATE", "END_DATE")
DT2 <- fread("ID    START_DATE    END_DATE
01    2007-09-11    2010-04-06
02    2008-06-06    2010-04-06
02    2011-09-09    2014-04-06")[, 
     (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols=cols]
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using a join to associate the tables and then a summarise

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "ID") %>% 
  mutate(employed = between(TAX_YEAR_END_DATE, START_DATE, END_DATE)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, TAX_YEAR_END_DATE) %>% 
  summarise(employed = any(employed))
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` and `lubridate` solution could be:

```
df1 %>%
 left_join(df2) %>%
 group_by(ID, TAX_YEAR_END_DATE) %>%
 summarise(STATUS = any(int_overlaps(interval(TAX_YEAR_END_DATE, TAX_YEAR_END_DATE),
                                     interval(START_DATE, END_DATE))))

     ID TAX_YEAR_END_DATE STATUS
  <int> <chr>             <lgl> 
1     1 2009-04-06        TRUE  
2     1 2010-04-06        TRUE  
3     1 2011-04-06        FALSE 
4     2 2010-04-06        TRUE  
5     2 2011-04-06        FALSE 
6     2 2012-04-06        TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a lookup data.frame for the durations in which ID was employed:
# dates_ro => data.frame
dates_ro <- data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df2, rownames(df2)), function(x){
      data.frame(id = x$ID, 
                 emp_date = seq.Date(x$START_DATE, x$END_DATE, by = "days"))
    }
  )
),
row.names = NULL)

# Lookup whether or not the person is employed at end date
# STATUS => character vector
df1$STATUS <- ifelse(is.na(
  match(df1$ID, dates_ro$id) &
    match(df1$TAX_YEAR_END_DATE, dates_ro$emp_date)),"UNEMPLOYED", "EMPLOYED")
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), TAX_YEAR_END_DATE = structure(c(14340, 
14705, 15070, 14705, 15070, 15436), class = "Date")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L), START_DATE = structure(c(13767, 
14036, 15226), class = "Date"), END_DATE = structure(c(14705, 
14705, 16166), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```